# SpringBoot: @EnableJpaRepositories, basePackageClasses ... repositories not found?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple Spring Boot project, that depends on a Library where some entities and repositories (`JpaRepository`) are defined. Additionally, I defined some repositories inside the project. All the repositories should be used inside one service.

In the Application.class I use:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = DatabaseConnectorsCoreMarker.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = 
{ThisApplication.class, DatabaseConnectorsCoreMarker.class})
```

In other projects we used the same but with only one `basePackageClasses`. That worked out. However, in the present case we always get errors like:

> Field *field_associated_to_repository* in *service_name* required a bean of type *repository_class* that could not be found.

Where *repository_class* are repository interfaces defined in `ThisApplication`.

Comment: Da you have a `@Repository` annotations?

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Nope?

Comment: You should have `@Repository` annotation or you class should extend `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` or one of the base repositories from package 'org.springframework.data.repository;'. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @AntonNovopashin Sorry for confusion, the repositories are interfaces extending `JpaRepository`.

Comment: They will still need to be annotated with @Repository. Only beans marked with Spring Stereotype annotations are eligible for autowiring.

Comment: @Dean Could you explain, why Spring `JpaRepository` isn't eligible for autowiring?

Comment: When spring component scans for beans it searches for classes annotated with spring Stereotype annotations. This how you tell spring the beans you want